# Applying Friedman Test on percentage of binary outcome

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, paired-comparisons

Is it correct to analyse data as described in the following?

- N Participants were asked to watch different videos showing the outline
  of a hand grasping an object.
- Four different types of hands were
  shown: a 'real' human hand (h_human), and three different
  'artificial' robotic hands (h_robot1, h_robot2, h_robot3).
- Additionally, not only one but 6 different grasping motions were
  shown.

All in all the participants watched 4*6=24 videos. After each video the were asked to decide whether they video showed a human hand (outcome 1) or a robotic hand (outcome 0).

The following questions are interesting for me:

1. Can the participants distinguish between the human hand and the robotic hands?
2. Which one of the three robotic hands appears to be most human-like

I was thinking about calculating the percentage/rate of human-likeness for each participant and hand over the grasping motions.

For example, for N=4 the original outcome looks like this (with P_i being participant i and G_j being grasping motion i)

```
     | H_human    | H_robot1   | H_robot2   | H_robot3   |
     | G1 G2 … G6 | G1 G2 … G6 | G1 G2 … G6 | G1 G2 … G6 |
-----------------------------------------------------------
P_1  | 1  1  …  0 | 1  1  …  0 | 0  1  …  0 | 1  1  …  0 | 
P_2  | 1  1  …  0 | 0  0  …  0 | 0  1  …  0 | 0  1  …  0 | 
P_3  | 1  0  …  1 | 0  1  …  0 | 1  0  …  0 | 0  0  …  1 |
P_4  | 0  1  …  1 | 0  1  …  0 | 0  1  …  1 | 1  1  …  1 |
```

This is reduced the an Nx4 Matrix if the human-like rate is calculated with Number_of_ones_per_hand/6:

```
     |H_human |H_robot1 |H_robot2 |H_robot3 |
----------------------------------------------
P_1  |  1.00  | 0.33    | 0.83    | 0.66   | 
P_2  |  0.66  | 0.50    | 0.83    | 0.50   | 
P_3  |  0.83  | 0.66    | 0.50    | 0.83   |
P_4  |  0.83  | 0.50    | 0.66    | 0.33   |
```

My questions are now:

1. Is it appropriate to just calculate this rate and use the Friedman Test on this Nx4 matrix?
2. Are the other methods better suited? (The number of participant will be around N=200)